# Appending screenshot to a variable in JS/jQuery to send to MongoDB in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to create a Chrome extension that will take a screenshot, save it as a variable so it can be sent to a MongoDB. I've been doing this in Javascript so far. [Here is the sample extension I've been basing it from](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) (CTRL + F "Test Screenshot Extension"). This is a project I've been working on as part of a team so I have no server knowledge, all I need to do it save the screenshot and have it ready to be sent to the server (I think the term is POST) at the press of a second button.

Here is my code and I've probably made a dozen mistakes but I hope I'm in the right area.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, { 
    format : 'png', 
    quality : '100'
  }, function(screenshot) {
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Screenshot', screenshot);
  })
})
```

I'm pretty sure the image now exists as a variable inside of `formData` and because I haven't declared it, it is a global variable. So it can be "GET" by the server? The Server is in jQuery. Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "iBug",
  "description": "This extension opens a bug reporting window",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This will file a bug reportg",
  "background": {
    "persistent" : false,
    "scripts": [ "/Javascript/screenshot.js" ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": ""
  },
  "icons": { 
    "128": "/images/TheBug.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", //affects the users active tab
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "tabs",
    "desktopCapture"//allows to capture the desktop screen
  ]
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, tell me what I've been doing wrong etc I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Just FYI being 'condescending' is generally considered a bad thing to be. I removed the reference to it in your question.

Comment: is there a rest API already accepting a form with no image? Do you know anything about forms and the types of data that can be sent with a form? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp and take a look on the enctype. Changing what a form is sending by to the server means you need to adapt also the form to accept that file as a resource. "multipart/form-data" is what you should look into and also ask your team if the server API supports "multipart/form-data" on the POST call related to that form.

Comment: @DincaAdrian I'm not too sure on the rest API accepting a form with no image. I'll get back to you on that. My entire team is new to coding too so I'm not sure the know either. I've been researching into Buffer, Multer, and Form tags (My terminology is crap) Not sure what enctype is so I'll look at that too. Thanks for giving me a direction to point my googlefu in I've been pretty lost. I'll get back to you later with hopefully more answers.

Comment: If your server is nodejs, multer is a good library and a 2 api call need to be created/edited. One for the upload of the image and one to save the data to mongo, with the path of the uploaded file. This is just the way I've did it in one of my projects so it's not the only way. Good luck coding